# Iterating Numbers and Alphabet for hashmap

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap, iteration

I'm trying to associate each letter of the alphabet with its corresponding number. 0=a, 1=b, 2=c, etc.

Although my numbers are sequencing properly, my letters are all coming out as "z." What am I doing wrong (with my loop)?

```
public static void cipherMap (Map<Integer, Character> map) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) { 
        for (Character alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++) {
            map.put(new Integer(i), alphabet);
        }   
    }
}
```

output:

```
0: z
1: z
2: z
3: z
4: z
5: z ... so on
```

Comment: Because you loop through the whole alphabet while at the same `i` iteration... Your values are just being overridden until z

Answer (score 2):

The last step of your inner loop sets every `i` to `z`. Remove the inner for loop and do something like,

```
public static void cipherMap (Map<Integer, Character> map) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) { 
        map.put(i, (char) ('a' + i));   
    }
}
```